# TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'offsetLeft') in Angular when using GSAP Helper Function

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, typeerror, gsap

I am getting this TypeError in chrome dev tools:

> TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'offsetLeft')
> in Angular

when using the GSAP Helper Function, and I am not sure how to solve this. The GSAP Helper Function is located on the official website https://greensock.com/docs/v3/HelperFunctions under the "Seamlessly loop elements along the x-axis" section. I declared the function at the top of my app.component.ts file, as well as created a javascript file in my angular project and then imported the helper function code into the JS file. I would copy the helper function into this question but it's pretty long that's why I shared an external link for it

Here is my app.component.ts file

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { gsap } from "gsap";
import { ScrollTrigger } from "gsap/ScrollTrigger";
import { Draggable } from "gsap/Draggable";
gsap.registerPlugin(Draggable, ScrollTrigger);

declare function horizontalLoop(items: number, config: any): any;

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent  {

  constructor() {}

  ngAfterViewInit() {
   
    horizontalLoop(8, "not sure what to put here");

  }
}
```

I know the javascript function works as is, as I have seen plenty of examples of the function working in plain javascript. So I'm assuming I am having a typescript and or angular problem. Any help would be greatly appreciated

UPDATE:
I added the parameters, but now I got a new error in chrome dev tools saying "Invalid property xPercent set to 0 Missing plugin? gsap.registerPlugin()" even though I imported the plugins as shown above in my app.component.ts

Comment: The function reffering to looks like ```fucntion horizontalLoop(items, config) {}``` and 4 lines down uses offsetLeft on items. And you're calling it without parameters?